# Sql COUNT Query with 3 columns and show in one template field of asp.net web page

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I am creating a asp.net web app with a small database of train reservation for learning. Im just in learning stage of asp.net so please excuse my mistakes.

**Situation :** i have two tables 1st Train_Details with columns of Train_No, 1AC-Berths, 2AC_Berths, 3AC_Berths. My second table is Passenger_Details with columns Train_No, Class_Type(where the user choose between 1AC,2AC OR 3AC).

**Problem:** im trying to create a query with columns mentioned below

```
Train no      Date of journey            Status (Template field)

ABC           18/03/2013                    
                                                 1AC : 
                                         2AC :
                                         3AC  :

Xyz         18/03/2013                1AC : 
                                      2AC :
                                      3AC :
```

**Requirement** : In  Status column, 1AC label should show {count no. of rows from PASSENGERS_Detail table where train no, DOJ, and class match as 1AC and show it as number}. Same situation for 2AC and 3AC too. all the labels of 1AC,2AC and 3AC should come under status column only for all trains no wise.

Comment: date of journey and status comes from which table. you havent mentioned that.

Comment: If you do not want `Train no` and `Date of journey` to repeat for every `STATUS` you should really solve that in C# and not SQL.

Comment: Jody, Im trying this for asp.net page. a little help in C# will be highly appreciable. But i have a newbie to C#

Comment: the date of journey is from the passenger table and status is just a template column i would like to create for displaying the desired results

Answer (score 0):

Some information is missing from your post, such as where `Date of journey` comes from. So with your limited information I managed to come up with:

```
SELECT
  p.Train_No, 
  CASE
    WHEN p.Class_Type = 1 THEN '1AC: '
    WHEN p.Class_Type = 2 THEN '2AC: '
    WHEN p.Class_Type = 3 THEN '3AC: '
  END + CAST(COUNT(p.Class_Type) AS NVARCHAR(50)) AS Status
FROM Train_Details AS t
JOIN Passenger_Details AS p
  ON p.Train_No = t.Train_No
GROUP BY p.Train_NO, p.Class_Type;
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/cda9b/2)

**EDIT:**

You would have to convert the Class_Type in your C# code aswell.

```
SELECT
  p.Train_No, 
  p.Class_Type,
  COUNT(p.Class_Type) AS Status
FROM Train_Details AS t
JOIN Passenger_Details AS p
  ON p.Train_No = t.Train_No
GROUP BY p.Train_NO, p.Class_Type;
```

Comment: Thanks for replying i tried this statement in access query wizard its showing a error when running this query as "Syntax error(missing operator)in query expression 'CASE"

Comment: You did not metion in your question that you were using access. I do not think access supports the `CASE` statement.

Comment: Sorry for that im using it as a backhand database for .net web application